# Reference of Krishna's last meeting with Yashoda when he promises to reincarnate as Venkateshwara?

Tags: krishna, bhagavata-purana, yashoda

There is a story of Krishna meeting Yashoda on her deathbed and she laments that she didn't get to witness any of his marriages. So Krishna promised her that in a future birth she would see him get married. Yashoda was reborn in the Kali Yuga as Vakuladevi, and she got to see the marriage of Venkateshwara.

What is the source for this story? Is it in the Bhagavata Purana? Can someone provide a link to the reference or a chapter where this story is mentioned?