# How many of Krishna's marriages were of the Brahma type?

Tags: krishna, marriage

[Reference of Krishna's last meeting with Yashoda when he promises to reincarnate as Venkateshwara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/56127/12489) says

> There is a story of Krishna meeting Yashoda on her deathbed and she laments that she didn't get to witness any of his marriages

We know from the Sudama story that Krishna DID have 16000 wives who lived at his palace.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23035/12489

> The gift of a daughter, after decking her (with costly garments) and honouring (her by presents of jewels), to a man learned in the Veda and of good conduct, whom (the father) himself invites, is called the Brahma rite

How many of Krishna's marriages were of the Brahma type?

Answer (score 3):

His marriage to Satyabhama -

*Taking personal initiative in the matter, Satrājit offered his daughter who was excellent in all respects as well as the Syamantaka jewel to him.
44. According to ritualistic formalities prescribed in the Śāstras the Lord married Satyabhāmā who was blessed with good disposition, charming beauty, generosity and other excellent virtues and had many suitors soliciting her hand.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128930.html